# SERS Gold nanoparticles performing poorly in organic solvents?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, spectroscopy, nanotechnology, raman

We have been working with some organic solvents lately and noticed a sharp decrease in surface-enhanced Raman spectroscopy (SERS) performance from our gold nanoparticles deposited in an organic solvent such as methanol.

With reference to the graph attached: the top line is 5 ppm Malachite Green Oxalate dissolved in water, the bottom line is 5 ppm Malachite Green Oxalate dissolved in 50/50 water/methanol

[image]

As you can see, the SERS performance of the gold nanoparticles decrease significantly when methanol is added.

We consulted our vendor and this is the explanation given: "*Since the nanoparticles are stabilized in an aqueous solutions, the addition of methanol will destabilize it. I think in this case there is too much methanol, so the nanoparticles are over-aggregating, hence the decrease in SERS performance*."

I have the following questions:

1. Why will the nanoparticles over aggregate in organic solvents? Is this specific to my vendor's nanoparticles?
2. Why would that even matter? How does over aggregation lead to poor SERS performance?
3. Since methanol is immiscible in water, shouldn't the analyte molecules (Malachite Green) on average have the same average distance to the SERS gold nanoparticles?

Comment: have you tested your zeta potential in both cases? This is the reason for the stability of the goldnanoparticles. If you got a zeta potential between -30mV and +30mV your colloid solution is instable. You should have less ions in the methanol mixture, which can cause a lower zeta potential. Best regards!

Comment: Methanol is miscible in water in all proportions. You want lots of particles of the right size and shape, whatever those happen to be.